# createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL: password authentication failed for user

Tags: postgresql, terminal, ruby-on-rails-4, homebrew, postgresql-9.2

Installed Postgresql via Homebrew. I wanted to create a new database after unzipping a ".tar". But I have this problem.

> Michael-Adelekes-MacBook:wikiful madeleke13$ sudo su postgres -c
>   'createuser-P--superuser madeleke13'
>
> bash: createuser-P--superuser: command not found
>
> Michael-Adelekes-MacBook:wikiful madeleke13$ sudo su postgres -c
>   'createuser-P-superuser madeleke13'
>
> bash: createuser-P-superuser: command not found
>
> Michael-Adelekes-MacBook:wikiful madeleke13$ sudo su postgres -c
>   'createuser -P --superuser madelek13'
>
> Password: Enter password for new role:  Enter it again:
>
> Michael-Adelekes-MacBook:wikiful madeleke13$ createdb -T template0
>
> newdbPassword:
>   Password:
>
> createdb: could not connect to database template1: FATAL:  password
>   authentication failed for user "madeleke13"
>
> Michael-Adelekes-MacBook:wikiful madeleke13$

I am not understanding why I'm unable to authenticate my username when I have had no problems before.

Comment: "I have had no problems before" - before what?

Comment: Nothing unusual in this error. Generally the `pg_hba.conf` rules are such that a random user has to provide a password to connect to a database. Edit it to use `trust` as the authentication method if you want passwordless connections.

Comment: My guess is that you're entering postgres' password for your account. Just a guess tho

Comment: A side comment, but I recommend instead of pasting links to screenshots of your terminal, just paste the terminal content. Easier for all of us.

Comment: Just updated for a clearer read. I have been using terminal, github, heroku, all else fine so I wonder why it could not authenticate. My password for Postgres and my username password are the same.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is the username in this command: `sudo su postgres -c 'createuser -P --superuser madelek13'`

Notice the username not the same as the user's account name: madeleke13. There's an 'e' missing in the username provided to the createuser command, thus the failed authentication.